# Get substring of an element's text value

Tags: javascript, string

```
<li id="li0" class="v1 ON"><div id="d0"><h3><a data-ltc="store-link-0" href=".?bID=2654" onclick="storeLocatorLite.showHideLi(0);return storeLocatorLite.getStoreDetails(2654, 0);"><b title="2654" class="hi">1</b>Test value<span class="distance">1.14 miles from search</span><span class="more"><i></i></span></a></h3></li>
```

The following JavaScript:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("v1 ON")[0];
list.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].text
```

is returning the string:

> 1.test value 19.18 miles from search

How do I return "test value"?

Comment: `text` is neither a DOM property, or function, and I don't see a class `v1 ON` anywhere

Comment: @SterlingArcher `a` elements have `text` property  (like `option` and `script`, there maybe others too). @OP Is there an actual pattern to find those words? If there isn't, the simplest way is `list = 'test value';`.

Comment: v1 on is added in the a tag , once you click on the a link

Comment: <li id="li0" class="v1 ON"><div id="d0"><h3><a data-ltc="store-link-0" href=".?bID=2654" onclick="storeLocatorLite.showHideLi(0);return storeLocatorLite.getStoreDetails(2654, 0);"><b title="2654" class="hi">1</b>Test value<span class="distance">1.14 miles from search</span><span class="more"><i></i></span></a></h3>

Comment: @user1036103 The pattern? Is the text you need always after a `b` element and always followed by a `span` for example? If that's the case, you can do `var list = document.querySelector('.v1 b').nextSibling.data;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* like you're trying to get just the text that's in the element itself, not in any of its child elements.

If so, you'll need to look through the element's `childNodes` and search for Text nodes.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("v1 ON")[0];
var node = list.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
var nodes = node.childNodes;

var t = "";

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
  var node = nodes[i];

  if (node.nodeType != 3) // TEXT_NODE
    continue;

  t += node.nodeValue;
}

console.log(t)     // prints "test value"
```

```html
<div class="v1 ON">
  <a data-ltc="store-link-0">
    <b title="3430" class="hi">1</b>test value
    <span class="distance">19.18 miles from search</span><span class="more"><i></i></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add span around your text and add id for it.

```
<a data-ltc="store-link-0" return storeLocatorLite.getStoreDetails(3430, 0);">
<b title="3430" class="hi">1</b><span id='text'>test value</span>
<span class="distance">19.18 miles from search</span><span class="more"><i></i></span></a>
```

And get text by id:

```
document.getElementById('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.text` is yielding all 3 text elements combined.

```
list.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].children[0].innerText
```

yields "1"

```
list.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].children[1].innerText
```

yields "1.14 miles from search"

and you want the thing in the middle.

So, you could just give the text you want in the middle a little wrapper element like a span to find it, and this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/u97xxku2/3/